# CSS Outer Div Moves with Inner Div

Tags: css, html

i've created a [CSS Desk](http://cssdesk.com/DA3Yd) example to help with my question.

I have an outer `div`, `.mainPage` and it has a child `div`, `.content`. When I set `.content`'s top margin to any size, `.mainPage` moves with the content.

I don't want that to happen, I want `.mainPage` `div` to stay at the top above the header, and the content to start `160px` down, which is below the header.

The header is `fixed` so that only the content moves, to give the really nice effect of the background.

Comment: What is your issue? http://jsbin.com/ILeroMEy/1/edit

Comment: My issue, is that I don't want `.mainPage` to move with the `.content`, i want it to stay top. @RokoC.Buljan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `margin-top` on the content element to `padding-top`, the background on `.main Page` will go below the header. Is that the effect you are going for?

Also, just to note, you don't have a `position` of relative, absolute or fixed set on `.mainPage,` so `z-index` won't work.

Comment: The padding trick works, however on my CSS Desk demo it still has a scroll bar... any way to get that to disappear

Comment: i don't see the scroll bar that you are worried about in my version of the demo - where is it? 'overflow:hidden' would probably hide it, depending, although it might also hide content. also since my solution worked for the original issue, I'd appreciate if you accepted it or upvoted it.